# JPA Entity not using @Column annotation

Tags: jboss, esb

I have the following simple entity:

```
   package net.plus.msodb.model;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(schema="msodb", name="mso")
    public class Mso implements Serializable {
 @Id
 private Integer incidentReference;

 private String detectedDate;
 private String detectedTime;
 private String startDate;
 private String startTime;
 private String anticipatedClearDate;
 private String anticipatedClearTime;
 private String actualClearDate;
 private String actualClearTime;
 private String headline;
 private String progress;
 private String details;
 private String servicesType;
 private String servicesCount;

 public Mso() {
 }

 @Column(name="detectedDate")
 public String getDetectedDate() {
  if(detectedDate == "") {
   return null;
  }

  return detectedDate + " " + detectedTime;
 }

        /*
         * Getters & Setters removed to save space
         */

 @Column(name="detectedDate")
 public void setDetectedDate(String detectedDate) {
  this.detectedDate = detectedDate;
 }

 public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
  this.startDate = startDate;
 }

 public void setAnticipatedClearDate(String anticipatedClearDate) {
  this.anticipatedClearDate = anticipatedClearDate;
 }

 public void setActualClearDate(String actualClearDate) {
  this.actualClearDate = actualClearDate;
 }

    }
```

and this is Smooks the config I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:jb="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/javabean-1.2.xsd">
  <params>
    <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
    <param name="inputType">input.xml</param>
    <param name="input.xml" type="input.type.actived">Workspace://MSODBActions/src/test/resources/msos.xml</param>
  </params>
  <jb:bean beanId="Mso" class="net.plus.msodb.model.Mso" createOnElement="/msos/mso">
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@actualClearDate" property="actualClearDate"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@actualClearTime" property="actualClearTime"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@anticipatedClearDate" property="anticipatedClearDate"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@anticipatedClearTime" property="anticipatedClearTime"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@details" property="details"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@detectedDate" property="detectedDate"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@detectedTime" property="detectedTime"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@headline" property="headline"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@incidentReference" decoder="Integer" property="incidentReference"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@progress" property="progress"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@servicesCount" property="servicesCount"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@servicesType" property="servicesType"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@startDate" property="startDate"/>
    <jb:value data="/msos/mso/@startTime" property="startTime"/>
  </jb:bean>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

When I try and save the entity, I get the following error:

```
Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'detectedDate' at row 1
```

You can see from the getter for detectedDate that if the detectedDate is an empty string (which it is if that attribute is missing from the source XML for the Smooks transformation) then the getter should return null.

Debugging this part of the code it does indeed return null.

It's almost like the getter isn't being used to get the value for detectedDate. If it were it would either be null, or at least a single space string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, the problem comes from the fact you can only annotate the member definitions or the methods, but not both. Notice I had annotated the @Id member variable & put the other annotations on the methods.

Move the @Id annotation to the getter for that field to solve the problem.